# re-do git subtree pull after revert

Tags: git, merge, git-subtree

I have a main repo called `mainrepo` and an external one called `auxrepo`.
Routinely, I do a git subtree pull of `auxrepo` into a directory within `mainrepo`, like so:

First I created a new branch in `mainrepo` called `aux-update` and then:

```
git remote add auxrepo git@git.example.com:example/auxrepo.git
git subtree add --squash --prefix=lib/auxrepo auxrepo auxrepo-branch
git subtree pull --squash --prefix=lib/auxrepo auxrepo auxrepo-branch
git commit
```

and then I will merge in the `aux-update` branch into `mainrepo`.

However, yesterday I did a pull of bad code from `auxrepo`, and had to push a revert of the changes to `mainrepo`. I did this via `git revert -m 1 $SHA` where `$SHA` was the sha from the merge of the `aux-update` branch.

Now today `auxrepo` has been fixed with new commits, and I want to pull in everything again with a subtree pull.

The problem is, when I just simply do my usual `git subtree pull --squash --prefix=lib/auxrepo auxrepo auxrepo-branch`, it only gets the new commits from today, and not the old commits that were reverted.

How can I subtree pull all the commits from `auxrepo`, including yesterday's commits and the new commits from today?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git revert $REVERTED_SHA
git subtree pull -squash --prefix=lib/auxrepo auxrepo auxrepo-branch
```

Where $REVERTED_SHA is the Sha of the commit you created when you did `git revert -m 1 $SHA`